# Google Closure not failing on incorrect type

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, jsdoc

I'm trying to write an annotation to a function which receives an array of objects.
I want the object to have certain mandatory attributes.

When I set a type of the inner object and check it, it works just fine.
But once I add the Array, the compiler "skips" test object type checking.

Here is a sample code ([run it](https://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home#code%3D%252F%252F%2520%253D%253DClosureCompiler%253D%253D%250A%252F%252F%2520%2540output_file_name%2520default.js%250A%252F%252F%2520%2540compilation_level%2520ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS%250A%252F%252F%2520%253D%253D%252FClosureCompiler%253D%253D%250A%250Aconst%2520myType%2520%253D%2520function()%2520%257B%257D%253B%250A%252F**%2520%2540type%2520%257B!string%257D%2520*%252F%250AmyType.prototype.arg1%253B%250A%250A%252F**%250A*%2520%2540param%2520%257BmyType%257D%2520input%250A*%252F%250Afunction%2520run_single(input)%2520%257B%250A%2520console.log(input)%253B%2520%250A%257D%250A%250A%252F**%250A*%2520%2540param%2520%257B!Array%253CmyType%253E%257D%2520input_arr%250A*%252F%250Afunction%2520run_array(input_arr)%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520console.log(input_arr)%253B%250A%257D%253B%250A%250A%250Avar%2520t%2520%253D%2520%257B%2522arg1%2522%253A%25201%257D%253B%250Arun_array(%255Bt%255D)%253B%250Arun_single(t)%253B))

(there seems to be a problem with the link, please copy&paste the code below)

```
// ==ClosureCompiler==
// @compilation_level ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS
// @output_file_name default.js
// @formatting pretty_print
// ==/ClosureCompiler==

/**
* @record
* @struct
*/
const myType = function() {};
/** @type {!string} */
myType.prototype.arg1;

/**
* @param {myType} input
*/
function run_single(input) {
 console.log(input); 
}

/**
* @param {!Array<myType>} input_arr
*/
function run_array(input_arr) {
    console.log(input_arr);
};


var t = {"arg1": 1};
run_array([t]);
run_single(t);
```

I'de expect `run_array` to fail. but it doesn't.
however, `run_single` is working properly.

```
JSC_TYPE_MISMATCH: actual parameter 1 of run_single does not match formal parameter
found   : {arg1: number}
required: (myType|null) at line 26 character 11
run_single(t);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is unfortunate but the Closure always infers array literals as Array of ?.  As ? will always match and this results in the behavior you are seeing.

You might consider using TypeScript which does better here